# Update CurrentRecord column depending on EmployeeVersion column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table containing the versions for each employee:

```
EmployeeId Status Department CurrentRecord EmployeeVersion
45         1      33         0             1
45         1      45         0             2
45         2      45         0             3
```

I want to update CurrentRecord and set it to 1 for the record having the maximum EmployeeVersion (as it is the latest version) like below:

```
EmployeeId Status Department CurrentRecord EmployeeVersion
45         1      33         0             1
45         1      45         0             2
45         2      45         1             3
```

This is my query:

```
UPDATE DimEmployeeSharedV1 
  SET CurrentRecord = 1 
WHERE EmployeeVersion = (
  SELECT MAX(e.EmployeeVersion)
  FROM DimEmployeeSharedV1 e
  WHERE e.EmployeeId = EmployeeId
  GROUP BY e.EmployeeId
)
```

I have the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: Why do you need `GROUP BY`? Also, change `UPDATE DimEmployeeSharedV1` to `UPDATE DimEmployeeSharedV1 V1` and `WHERE e.EmployeeId=EmployeeId` to `WHERE e.EmployeeId=V1.EmployeeId`

Comment: 'I want to update CurrentRecord and set it to 1' - why? It's not a good idea to store data which can be derived and what happens if/when version 4 comes along - then you have to reset all previous versions as well?l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use updatable cte :

```
with ucte as (
     select v.*, row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId order by EmployeeVersion) as seq
     from DimEmployeeSharedV1 v
)
update ucte 
     set CurrentRecord = 1 
where seq = 1;
```

Correlated sub-query will also work :

```
UPDATE v1
      SET v1.CurrentRecord = 1 
FROM DimEmployeeSharedV1 v1
WHERE v1.EmployeeVersion = (SELECT MAX(e.EmployeeVersion) 
                            FROM DimEmployeeSharedV1 e
                            WHERE e.EmployeeId = v1.EmployeeId
                           );
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=09554e0df960708f03c2013a2e4baea6)

```
; WITH cte as(
 select EmployeeId, max(EmployeeVersion) as EmployeeVersion
 from #A
 group by EmployeeId
)
update a
set CurrentRecord = 1
from #A a
inner join cte on a.EmployeeId = cte.EmployeeId and a.EmployeeVersion = cte.EmployeeVersion
```

**Output**

[image]